# Assign ASP.NET MVC model to AngularJS scope

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Below the code of my view (the javascript code is in the view, just temp just for testing).

I'd like assign the ASP.NET MVC model (`@Model`) to the AngularJS scope (`$scope.person`)

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

The view

```
@model MyApp.Person

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.person = ?????
}]);
</script>
```

**Update 1 :**
I tried this code, in the JS file :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.person = @Html.Raw(window.person);
}]);
```

In the view file :

```
<script>
    @{
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    }
    window.person = serializer.Serialize(Model);
</script>
```

I get 2 errors :

```
ReferenceError: serializer is not defined (on windows)
window.person = serializer.Serialize(Model);

SyntaxError: illegal character (it's the @)
$scope.person = @Html.Raw(window.person);
```

Comment: The 'illegal character' is just an 'false' IntelliSense assumption. When surrounded with '' the error will go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
    @{
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(Model);
    }
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.person = @Html.Raw(json);
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Work but only when the code is in the view and not in a separated JS file.

Comment: @Kris-I like Satpal said,  //Store data in global variable.

Comment: in the js file, $scope.person = window.person;  in the view file, window.person = @serializer.Serialize(Model); or put this line in the brackets.

Comment: Reference error on "ReferenceError: serializer is not defined", in the bracket it's worst.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    }
        window.person = @Html.Raw(serializer.Serialize(Model));

        console.log(window.person);

    </script>

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this will work with Angular.

You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
window.person = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //Store data in global variable.
```

In Your angular code use,

```
$scope.person = window.person
```

However, Best solution will be to create a service and fetch the person data using the service.

*Complete Code*

```
@model MyApp.Person

<script>
window.person = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //Store data in global variable.
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.person = window.person
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: The question is with angularJS. When I add this line, all the AngularJS code not work anymore.

Comment: Same, AngularJS code not work anymore. The best solution is not use AngularJS I think.

Comment: In the view, it's temp will be move to separated JS file

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. this will work. 
in your view:

```
<script>
    myApp.value('person', @Html.Raw(Model));
</script>
```

and in your (angular) controller:

```
myApp.controller('personController', ['$scope', '$http', 'person' function ($scope, $http, person) {
    console.log(person);
}]);
```

If you "inject" your json value on your controller, you are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

At first assign value in global java script variable then use it in your separate angular file

```js
 <script>
   var obj =  '@Html.Raw(Model)';
</script>
```

now in your angular page

```js
$scope.person = obj;
```